# Correctly expanding an HTML widget

Tags: html, css, css-float

HTML and CSS layout remains a bit of a black art to me, so I'd appreciate any help in what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'm in the process of creating a JavaScript API for our company's "widget", so that folks can include it on their websites. If the user presses a button within that widget, I want to increase the size of the widget, say from 300x200 to 600x400. So far so good, a little bit of JS and I'm happy. But there are two constraints:

(1) I want to "overflow" anything larger than 300x200 onto the page, i.e., I don't just increase the size of the host `<div>` tag so that other elements on the page move out of the way; I actually want to cover over other elements in the page.

(2) I want to do this intelligently, so that if the widget is on the left-hand side of the page, it will expand to the right; if it's on the right-hand side of the page, it should expand to the left; if it's on the top, it should expand towards, the bottom; and if it's on the bottom, it should expand upwards towards the top.

I presume that some appropriate combination of position/display/float CSS properties is what I'll need - but I haven't yet been able to wrap my head around the precise combination required.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 12/8/11 -

Just for future reference, I ended up using the jquery UI [position()](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138026/Position) overload to help me out with the positioning. This is the code that I ended up using:

```
// Create a placeholder object and then hide the engage display element.
var host = engageObject.getHost();
var engageHost = engageObject.getEngageHost();
var parent = engageObject.getParentElement();
this.mPlaceholder = document.createElement('div');
$(this.mPlaceholder)
    .width($(engageHost).width())
    .height($(engageHost).height())
    .css('float', 'left');
parent.insertBefore(this.mPlaceholder, host);
$(engageHost).hide();

// Update the host's layout
this.mOriginalHostPositioning = $(host).css('position');
this.mOriginalHostWidth = $(host).width();
this.mOriginalHostHeight = $(host).height();
$(host).width($(this.mConnectHost).width());
$(host).height($(this.mConnectHost).height());
$(host).css('position', 'absolute');

// If we would otherwise spill out of the window on the right or the bottom,
// make sure we expand in the correct direction.
var topLeft = $(parent).offset();
var right = topLeft.left + $(this.mConnectHost).width();
var bottom = topLeft.top + $(this.mConnectHost).height();
var posStr;
if (right > $(window).width()) {
    posStr = "right ";
} else {
    posStr = "left ";
}
if (bottom > $(window).height()) {
    posStr += "bottom";
} else {
    posStr += "top";
}
$(host).position({ my: posStr, at: posStr, of: parent });
```

Effectively, I create a new `placeholder` image that's the same size as the original, unexpanded widget (`engageHost`), hide the original widget, and then position my new `connectHost` to the appropriate corner of the original parent element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Z-Index property of CSS is what you're looking for.  Just pulling the entire div to a higher Z-Index may solve your problem.  Alternatively you may want to reserve the space behind the widget.  Use an empty div like this:

```
<!-- The following div takes up the space behind the floating applet.  In your case 300x200 or 600x400 ect -->
<div style="width:300; height:200; float:left;">&nbsp;</div>

<!-- The following div is where your widget goes (floating above the rest of the page) -->
<div style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:2;"> 
    Your widget code here
</div>


<div style="clear:both">
    Other code on the website here.
</div>
```

Relevant W3 Schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: I think the placeholder `<div>` with its float property set, plus the 'position:absolute' in my target `<div>` is most of what I was looking for, at least with respect to #1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

2) Use javascript - calculate the position on the screen and apply classes based on that position. Have 4 different CSS classes each will expand the widget in different direction and just apply them to you widget.

Comment: Good idea to have the four different CSS classes. Thanks.